Issues with Snowflake stored procedure: complex logic fails to execute properly
I'm trying to create a Snowflake stored procedure that orchestrates data processing for multiple steps defined in a control table. The procedure iterates over these steps and dynamically builds INSERT statements based on parameters like PROCESS_INDEX, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, and periodicity (e.g., daily, weekly, monthly). However, I'm encountering errors, and I'm not sure where the logic breaks.
Here is the code for my procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE --(
    PROCESS_INDEX NUMERIC,
    DATE_FROM VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    DATE_TO VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE 
    calculated_date_from DATE;
    calculated_date_to DATE;
    step INT;
    function_name STRING;
    source_table STRING;
    dimensions STRING;
    lag_time INT;
    notes STRING;
    final_query STRING DEFAULT '';
    period_value STRING;
    periodo ARRAY;
BEGIN
    FOR row_index IN (
        SELECT INDEX STEP, FUNCTION_NAME, SOURCE_TABLE, DIMENSIONS, PERIOD, LAG_TIME, NOTES
        FROM --
        WHERE INDEX = :PROCESS_INDEX
        ORDER BY STEP
    )
    DO
        step := row_index.STEP;
        function_name := row_index.FUNCTION_NAME;
        source_table := row_index.SOURCE_TABLE;
        dimensions := row_index.DIMENSIONS;
        lag_time := row_index.LAG_TIME;
        notes := row_index.NOTES;
        periodo := row_index.PERIOD;

        FOR period_row IN (SELECT VALUE AS period_value FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => periodo))) 
        DO
            IF (:DATE_FROM IS NULL OR :DATE_TO IS NULL) THEN
                CASE LOWER(period_row.period_value)
                    WHEN 'daily' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE());
                        calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, 1, calculated_date_from);
                    WHEN 'weekly' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(WEEK, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'WEEK'));
                        calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, 6, calculated_date_from);
                    WHEN 'monthly' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(MONTH, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'MONTH'));
                        calculated_date_to := LAST_DAY(calculated_date_from);
                    WHEN 'year' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YEAR');
                        calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE());
                    WHEN 'lifetime' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YEAR');
                        calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE());
                    ELSE
                        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unsupported periodicity: %', period_row.period_value;
                END CASE;
            ELSE
                calculated_date_from := TO_DATE(:DATE_FROM, 'AUTO');
                calculated_date_to := TO_DATE(:DATE_TO, 'AUTO');
            END IF;

            final_query := final_query || '
                INSERT INTO --(
                    PERIOD_COLUMN, 
                    START_DATE, 
                    END_DATE, 
                    REGION, 
                    PLATFORM, 
                    SUBS_PARTNER, 
                    STREAMS, 
                    ACTIVATIONS, 
                    EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP, 
                    NOTES
                )
                SELECT 
                    ''' || period_row.period_value || ''' AS PERIOD_COLUMN,
                    ''' || calculated_date_from || ''' AS START_DATE, 
                    ''' || calculated_date_to || ''' AS END_DATE, 
                    REGION, 
                    DISTRIBUTION_PLATFORM AS PLATFORM, 
                    SUBS_PARTNER, 
                    STREAMS, 
                    NULL AS ACTIVATIONS,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP, 
                    ''' || notes || ''' AS NOTES
                FROM TABLE(
                    CALL --(
                        ''' || function_name || ''',
                        ''' || dimensions || ''',
                        ''' || source_table || ''',
                        ''' || period_row.period_value || ''',
                        ''' || calculated_date_from || ''',
                        ''' || calculated_date_to || '''
                    )
                )';
        END FOR;
    END FOR;

    RETURN final_query;
END;

Expected behavior: the procedure dynamically generates SQL queries based on the control table (orq_table_eagu).
It calculates the calculated_date_from and calculated_date_to dates, based on the periodicity and input dates.
It should return the complete SQL string (final_query).
Issues encountered

Error in iterating over PERIOD values: the PERIOD column is an array. I'm using FLATTEN to iterate, but I'm not sure if I'm handling it correctly.
 SELECT VALUE AS period_value 
 FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => periodo)) 

might not work as expected.

Date calculations may not behave as intended: some branches in the CASE statement might cause issues (e.g., ADD_DAYS is not valid as written).

Concatenating the final_query: building a long SQL string dynamically might introduce syntax errors or unexpected results.

Debugging challenges: I can't see the intermediate values of variables like step, calculated_date_from, calculated_date_to, period_value, etc., while debugging. Snowflake doesn't support PRINT.


What I've tried

Manually running individual pieces of the procedure to verify correctness.
Adding RAISE EXCEPTION statements to simulate debugging, but it's not ideal.
Splitting complex sections into smaller procedures for testing.

Questions
Is the FLATTEN logic correct for iterating over the PERIOD array?
How can I debug the procedure effectively to see intermediate values during execution?
Are there any known issues with building dynamic SQL strings like this in Snowflake stored procedures?
How would you refactor this procedure to improve clarity and maintainability?
Example data - here's a sample row from orq_table_eagu:
orq_table_eagu
I tried iterating over the PERIOD array using FLATTEN to extract individual periodicity values (e.g., daily, monthly) and dynamically calculate date ranges based on these values. I expected the procedure to correctly handle the array, compute the dates, and build a valid SQL query stored in final_query.
However, I encountered issues where:

The FLATTEN logic might not properly iterate over the array in all cases.
The dynamic SQL string (final_query) sometimes fails due to syntax issues or unexpected null values.
Debugging intermediate values like step, period_value, or calculated_date_from is challenging since Snowflake doesn't have native debugging tools like PRINT.

I was expecting to successfully generate a complete SQL query that I could then execute or validate.

Hi - this may just be a language issue but I don’t understand why your question states that errors may/might occur. Do errors actually occur, or not, and if they do occur can you update your question with the actual error message you are getting, along with enough sample data to allow someone to replicate the issue? Also, on this forum you need to limit yourself to a single question - so what’s the actual issue you want help with?

If it returns an error, the problem is that my procedure does not iterate effectively (the iteration using the 2nd FOR seems to be the one that has the problem). The error is when I want to iterate over the period variable (period contains an array of dates, for example: ('daily', 'weekly') ), if I want to iterate between the values ​​of that array, for example first take daily, generate the final_query, and then do it with weekly and so on with all the other index and steps.
